# Android: Possible solution for updating the custom list view at random times

Tags: android, listview

I am having a situation where I want to update my Custom List View using BaseAdapter whenever my Database is updated. I have tried calling invalidate() on this Custom List but it didn't work, similarly I even tried having a timer to update my list after sometime, that didn't work either. Please let me know of possible solution.

**Update:**

This is how I am making my custom list view

```
li= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.id_lv_row); 
ColorDrawable divcolor = new ColorDrawable(Color.DKGRAY); 
registerForContextMenu(li); 
li.setDivider(divcolor); 
li.setDividerHeight(2); 
li.setAdapter(new FriendsPositionAdapter(this));
```

Comment: This is how I am making my custom list view                     `li= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.id_lv_row);
ColorDrawable divcolor = new ColorDrawable(Color.DKGRAY);
registerForContextMenu(li);                                           and this is how I am trying to call notifyDataChanged on my CustomAdapter `FriendsPositionAdapter fda = new FriendsPositionAdapter(myContext);
fda.notifyDataSetChanged();
FriendsPosition.Updater gg= new Updater();`
li.setDivider(divcolor);
li.setDividerHeight(2);
li.setAdapter(new FriendsPositionAdapter(this));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalidate is for repainting views only, you have to tell to the List adapter (BaseAdapter) that dataset has changed.
When the data changes, asign the new dataset to the adapter, and later call notifyDataSetChanged()...

in order to make functional notifyDataSetChanged() the adapter data must be changed. Remember that the original data that change is not reflected automatically to the adapter.

```
//here i retrieve the new list, named "beans"
lista = (BeanList) result.getDataObject();
Vector<Bean>beans = list.getBeanList();
((BeanListAdapter)listAdapter).syncData(beans);
((BeanListAdapter)listAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

//now the syncData method
public void syncData( List<PINPropiedad> newData ){
    for(Object o : newData){
        add(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give some code, I dont understand how to call notifyDataChanged() etc

Comment: Thanks mate, just had to add the handler code to your fix and done!

Answer (score 3):

[`BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) should do the trick as long as the data behind the adapter actually changed. That's all you need to do to refresh the list.

Comment: But how would the adapter know that which listview it is connected to?

Comment: That's just the method to use. You'd have to do li.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(). But you also have to update the data behind the Adapter. How are you doing that?

Comment: `dh= new DataHelper(context);
FriendAndStatusList=dh.getActiveRequestsStatus();`                     Then I am passing this list to the Adapter.
  `

Comment: I can't get this method li.getAdapter().notifyDataChanged()